# Error to execute Flutter project on Android using Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, visual-studio-code, firebase-authentication

I'm trying start a Flutter project on Android but I got a error when I start the debug. I've followed the Firebase guide when I created the project and added firebase auth to pubspec.yaml file. I not change the project created by `flutter create` tool and I've copied the `google-services.json` to project folder.

**pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+12
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+8
```

**project/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

**project/app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Error shown on Debug Console**

```
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Initializing gradle...                                              1.9s
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarDebug'...                          17.2s
Gradle task assembleAarDebug failed with exit code 1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/augustosansoncadini/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 946

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:buildPluginDebugFirebaseAuth'.
> Process 'command '/Users/augustosansoncadini/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to open project into Android Studio and run build

Comment: When I start from Android Studio eh app is opened but on Visual Studio Code not works

Comment: Does any flutter project run at all with your vs code?